# Rails - Form not posting in external API due to parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

heres my model thats handling my form

```
class Form
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Translation
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :config, :client, :subject, :email, :custom_field, :phone_number_28445, :company_28445, :description

  validates_presence_of :subject, :message => '^Please enter your name'
  validates_presence_of :description, :message => '^Question(s), and/or feedback can not be blank'
  validates :email, presence: true  
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end

    self.config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/fresh_desk.yml")[Rails.env]
self.client = Freshdesk.new(config[:url], config[:api_key], config[:password])
  end

  def post_tickets
    client.post_tickets({
      :subject => "Web Inquiry From, #{subject}", 
      :email => email,
      :custom_field => {:phone_number_28445 => phone_number_28445},
      :description => description
     }) 
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

in my post_tickets method it works fine....the problem is with the

```
:custom_field_phone_number_28445 => custom_field_phone_number_28445
```

I know this because as soon as i take that out the form posts.......when i add it back in i get a

```
   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1222ms


   Freshdesk::ConnectionError (Connection to the server failed. Please check hostname):
   lib/freshdesk.rb:77:in `rescue in block in fd_define_post'
   lib/freshdesk.rb:70:in `block in fd_define_post'
   app/models/form.rb:25:in `post_tickets'
   app/controllers/website/contacts_controller.rb:8:in `create'
   config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:8:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

heres whats getting posted when it works

```
 Parameters: 
   {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g91E0jYezX+5gFAe6R/hUPs9b+UqS1uMqki4rE6xU28=", 

   "contacts"=>{"subject"=>"ricky ahn ", 
   "email"=>"ricky@onehouse.net", 
   "custom_field"=>{"phone_number_28445"=>"123-123-1234"}, 
   "description"=>"test"}, 

   "commit"=>"Submit"}

   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contacts/new
   Completed 302 Found in 2142ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

heres what gets posted when it doesent work

```
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g91E0jYezX+5gFAe6R/hUPs9b+UqS1uMqki4rE6xU28=",
    "contacts"=>{"subject"=>"ricky ahn ", 
    "email"=>"ricky@onehouse.net", 
    "custom_field"=>{"phone_number_28445"=>"123-123-1234"}, 
    "description"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 841ms
```

i dont know what i'm doing wrong right here....

here is the html/haml

```
= form_for(:contacts, url: contacts_path) do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  = f.label :subject, "Name"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  = f.text_field :subject, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br    
  = f.label "Email"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  %br    
  = f.email_field :email, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br
  = f.label "Phone"   
  %br    
  = f.fields_for :custom_field do |custom_field|
    = custom_field.text_field :phone_number_28445, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br
  = f.label "Question(s), and/or feedback"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  %br
  = f.text_area :description, class: "text_field width_100_percent", style: 'height: 100px;'
  %br
  %br
  = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-warning'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify this name for a reason?  The value that's causing a problem is the only one w/an overridden form name.

```
= f.text_field :custom_field_phone_number_28445,
   name: 'contacts[custom_field][phone_number_28445]',
   class: "text_field width_100_percent"
```

Shouldn't it just be:

```
= f.text_field :custom_field_phone_number_28445,
   class: "text_field width_100_percent"
```

All the other attributes aren't nested into a sub-name on the form...  I'm guessing that value isn't being set in the form model, ends up nil, and something down the chain is mad about that.

Comment: yeah i had to specify a name on it originally because it had to be passed in like that...otherwise it would not post...so im thinking it has something to do with that but i dont know how to post it like that in the method in my model

Comment: when i dont specify a name the parameters look like this "custom_field_phone_number_28445"=>"123-123-1234" which throws an error it should look like this "custom_field"=>{"phone_number_28445"=>"123-123-1234"},

Comment: But what you're submitting with the form is not what you're posting to the service.  You're submitting to your rails app, and the format needs to match your `Form` object.  Once your form object contains the information correctly, you can move on to figuring out the `post_tickets` API call.

Comment: Yeah thats what im trying to do...can't figure out what it wants though

Comment: so i have a parameter called :custom_field and :phone_number_28445 how can i merge those two together in the form view?  i've tried **:custom_field, :phone_number_28445** but did not work

Comment: Make your form object look how your form will submit, so instead of the `:custom_field_phone_number_XXXXX` attribute, just have `:phone_number`.  Change the HAML form field to `:phone_number`, and now the form object will get that value.  After it's in the form object, now you can use the `phone_number` attribute in your `post_tickets` method, I'd guess it would be something like `:custom_field => { :phone_number => phone_number }` but I've never used that API.

Comment: hey so that got it to not error out....but its not posting the phone_number to the site....when i change the code to ':custom_field => {:phone_number => custom_field}' it posts but it posts the whole thing...when i try to just get the phone number by :custom_field => {:phone_number => phone_number} i get nothing on the site.....is it because of my initialize method in my model?

Comment: Hard to say, I'd try adding some `puts` calls to see what's going on.  In `post_tickets`, you could print that hash out before you send it, to see if it has what you expect it to.

Comment: `custom_field"=>{"phone_number_28445"=>"123-123-1234"}` thats how the hash is coming out in my terminal....it is what i was expecting...i dont understand why it wont post with phone_number....but it does post with custom_field

Comment: Well, that's good. :)  It sounds like you may have a new FreshDesk client question now though...  I've never used it...  Good luck!